# Can i unplug my cintiq from my computer?

Tags: laptop

I got a Wacom cintiq 16 a little while ago but I don't have a home computer so I'm just plugging and unplugging it into my laptop, will that effect it at all? can I just plug and unplug whenever?

Answer (score 2):

USB can be plugged a certain number of times before damage occurs.
I have heard the number of 1500 insertions mentioned in that connection,
but I have not found any official reference for it.

If we base the calculations on that number and two insertions per day,
we get a bit more than two years, but these are just numbers that may have
no connection with reality.

I suggest in any case to not plug it in using excessive force.
Treat it gently and it will last longer.